# Create existing txt file with incremental numbers (c#)

Tags: c#

I have a txt file in a folder, I want to copy and paste that same txt file in the same folder 50  times with an incremental numbers.

Example :

Existing txt file =. Mytext.txt

Then it gets pasted like following :
Mytext-0001.txt
Mytext-0002.txt
...
Mytext-0050.txt
Etc...

Could you guys please help me in doing it.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds great.  You can do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string PathFiletoCopy = @"C:\temp\out.csv";
        string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(PathFiletoCopy);
        string PartialNewPathFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(PathFiletoCopy), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(PathFiletoCopy) + "-");

        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            System.IO.File.Copy(PathFiletoCopy, PartialNewPathFile + i.ToString("D4") + Extension);
```

Comment: Thaaaaanks a lot!! Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Mat be can you click on up arrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pasting it is not pssible... This would mean you have to inject your code to the explorer.exe...

But there is a better way to do so:

Create a c#-Console App and do the following:

```
string dir = @"C:\Path\To\Dir";
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
     // i will now be from 0 to 1000
     // i.ToString("D4"). Converts the number to a string with padding '0's before... e.g: 0001, 0010, 0200, 1000...   
     string filename = "MyFile-" + i.ToString("D4") + ".txt";
     using(var s = System.IO.File.Create(dir + "\\" + filename)) {
          // If you want, you can write no content to the file using
          // s.Write(...). or creating a System.IO.StreamWriter
     } 
}
```

More Information can be found using MSDN.

Comment: _"Pasting it is not pssible... This would mean you have to inject your code to the explorer.exe"_ - incorrect. A process may simply use the Windows Explorer to navigate a namespace; find an item and perform `IDataObject` operations.  No injection required.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776903(v=vs.85).aspx#Extracting_Shell_Data